# Unable to list machinesets on Openshift 4.10 cluster

Tags: openshift, redhat, openshift-client-tools, openshift-enterprise

I am using the below code snippet to list machinesets but unable to get back any machinesets on the cluster:

```
cfg, err := config.GetConfig()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    opts := manager.Options{Scheme: scheme.Scheme}

    mgr, err := manager.New(cfg, opts)
    if err != nil {
        klog.Fatal(err)
    }
    //Get client from manager
    r = mgr.GetClient()
    msList := &machinev1.MachineSetList{}
    r.List(context.TODO(), msList, client.InNamespace(namespace_to_list))

    klog.Infof("len, %d", len(msList.Items))
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks

Comment: Are you receiving an error, or an empty response, or something else? Can you successfully list machinesets from the command line (using `kubectl` or `oc`)?

Comment: @larsks yes I can list from the command line. I do not get any error, length of machineset is zero in the above code snippet

Comment: @asm for machinev1 which package have you used ?